# 特定の条件を満たす行のみを削除するには？

Tags: python, pandas

特定の条件を満たす行のみを選択して、データセット全体から削除したいと考えています。
pandasのdataframeにdfというデータがあります。
この中から、「同意しません」とある行全体をデータから削除したいと考えています。

現在のところ、
不同意のサンプルをselection1というグループにして、
dfから、該当する行全体、データから削除しようとしているのですが、この部分がうまく行きません。
もし条件の指定と、その条件に見合うデータのみを削除する方法を
ご存じでしたら、ご教示頂けますとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['同意します', '同意しません', '同意します', '同意しません',]},
    index=[1, 2, 3, 4, ])

consent_dic = {"同意します":1, "同意しません":0}
df["consent"] = df.apply(lambda row: consent_dic[row["x"]], axis=1)

#不同意のサンプルを選択
selection1 = df.consent==0

#不同意のサンプルを削除 ?
df.drop(df.consent.selection1)
```

Comment: まぁ、`consent_dic` は必要なくて、`df.drop(df.index[df.x == '同意しません'], inplace=True)` とでもすれば良いかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「同意します」のみ残すことができました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

次のコマンドで、実行できました。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['同意します', '同意しません', '同意します', '同意しません',]},
    index=[1, 2, 3, 4, ])

df.drop(df.index[df.x == '同意しません'], inplace=True)
```